# jplayer provide two files of different audio format

Tags: jquery, jplayer

My Jplayer code 
i have to also add mp3 format for more browser support, please help ..
now there is only .ogg file format... it doesnot support IE7

```
$("#jpId1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () { // The $.jPlayer.event.ready event
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { // Set the media
                oga: "sound/cookingloop.ogg"
            }).jPlayer("stop"); // Attempt to auto play the media
        },
        ended: function () { // The $.jPlayer.event.ended event
            $(this).jPlayer("play"); // Repeat the media
        },
        supplied: "oga",
        solution: "html,flash",
   }

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code from jplayer website

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
   ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      mp3: "/media/mysound.mp3",
      oga: "/media/mysound.ogg"
   });
   },
   swfPath: "/js",
   supplied: "mp3, oga"
});
```

I have worked  it with mp3 so it works  [jplayer](http://jplayer.org/)

Comment: tHANKS DEEPAK , in actual i am working with .ogg file, but IE 7 doeasnot support .ogg file , so would you provide any better answer please, and  what is Swf path in your answer please? swFPath:"/JS"

Comment: i think you are familiar with jplayer swf file which come with it so it define the path of that swf file, and i m working on linix system so i don't have ie 7 but i think if you give mp3 together that then it should work. My previous client didn't send me any error for that all the best:)

Comment: i am not please explain? as i am new to this topic

Comment: about swf i found it when i download it from jplayer website and there is a swf file in a folder. And i have to set only path in to swfPath variable in js nothing else i think you haven't yet get the download the demo source code for that https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer

Comment: download from this link

Comment: Thnx Deepak for your better help :) :)